# How do you say something is "very alcoholic"?

Tags: vocabulary

I'm continuously confused on how to best say something is alcoholic. For example, I have heard
酒精很强， 很有酒精 , But I've also heard "酒量很高“ or ”酒量很大”

Could someone clarify which of these is the most common/which might be bad translations?

Comment: 酒量很大 generally refers to somebody's ability to drink without getting drunk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my understanding, `alcoholic` has two meanings in English:

1. (Something) contains or is related to alcohol.
2. (Someone) is addicted to alcohol or is affected by alcoholism.

For the first meaning, in Chinese we say `含有酒精的` or `酒精含量高的`. E.g.

> Alcoholic drink 含酒精的饮品 or simply 酒精饮品

For the second, we use the word `酗酒(成性)` (adj.) or `酗酒者/酒鬼` (noun).

> He is an alcoholic. 他酗酒成性 or 他是个酒鬼。

---

Regarding the Chinese phrases in your question,

酒精很强，很有酒精 means #1 but don't sound natural without context.

"酒量很高“ or ”酒量很大” means someone is good at drinking. `酒量` is not the short form of `酒精含量`, but one word meaning 'the ability of a person to hold liquor'.

Comment: so 酒量  refers to how much alcohol a person can take, correct?

Comment: Would you say "高“ or ”大“ ？

Comment: @Stephen 酒量 is usually associated with 大. 酒精含量/浓度 is usually connected with 高, although 大 is also correct and common.